# HTTPヘッダーからステータスコードを取得したい

Tags: javascript

こんにちは。
質問させてください。
HTTPヘッダーからステータスコードを取得したいのですが、可能ですか？
言語はjavascriptです。

Comment: もう少し実施したいことを詳細に追記していただくとより回答が付きやすいかと思います。例えばJavascriptが実行されるのはブラウザ上で、特定のAPIをAjaxでリクエストした時のレスポンスヘッダーのステイタスコードを確認したい。などなど

Comment: すみませんでした。やりたいことはkeitaro_soさんの書いてある通りです。

Answer (score 2):

たとえば、 `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1` という API へリクエストを送信し、その HTTP レスポンスステータスコードを取得したうえで、それをデバッガの Web コンソールに出力するためには、以下のように **Fetch API** を用いることが出来ます。ここで、 HTTP レスポンスステータスコードの取得には、 `Response.status` プロパティを使用します<sup>[[1]](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dom-response-status)</sup>。

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')
  .then(response => console.log(response.status)); //=> 200

fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/100')
  .then(response => console.log(response.status)); //=> 404
```

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", () => {
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1')
    .then(response => console.log(response.status)); //=> 200

  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/100')
    .then(response => console.log(response.status)); //=> 404
});
```

```html
<button>fetch</button>
```